# Black and Yellow dots on Scallions

Tags: diagnosis, vegetables, diseases, outdoor, spring-onions

I'm new to gardening and well recently I decided to try to grow scallions from leftover Scallion ends. first I placed them in water to grow them out a bit then I planted them in a random pot that had dirt in it. Anyways the reason why I'm posting here today is because I'm concerned about these black dots/bumps on the scallions. plus there's like some yellowy balls too you can see them most prominently in the water droplet on the left in the first picture I sent. I'm severely worried about my scallions and don't know what to do or what it is. based on what I've read online it could be onion aphids or onion smut, but I'm genuinely not sure what it is, so I'm really worried. If anyone can tell me anything or help me diagnose the issue I'd really appreciate it. Thanks for taking the time to read this and hopefully replying.

[image: Scallion 1]
[image: Scallion 2]
[image: Scallion 3]