# Scallions wilting/dying?

Tags: plant-health, wilt, spring-onions

I'm the same writer as [This](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/52948/black-and-yellow-dots-on-scallions). I've been checking my scallions the past few days and well... They don't seem well... The Scallions on the top and bottom of the picture appear to be wilting or dying, and the one on the left doesn't seem to have grown much if any greens... I'm really worried about them. any tips or suggestions?
[image: Scallions]